# Typescript BigInt addition issue: Cannot mix BigInt and other types, use explicit conversions

Tags: typescript, bigint

We are seeing the following compilation error on our build servers:

```js
    TypeError: Cannot mix BigInt and other types, use explicit conversions
 
      119 |       const one: bigint = BigInt(1);
      120 |       const oldNum: bigint = oldLabelNumber.currentValue;
    > 121 |       const localLabelNum: bigint = oldNum + one;
```

I have explicitly typed the variables `one` and `oldNum` to try and prove to the type checker that I am doing BigInt addition to no avail.

For context, this is what the code has become in an attempt to coerce the type checker into believing me that I'm doing `bigint` operations.. (Originally it was a simple ternary expression)

```js
    const oldLabelNumber = await fetchLabelNumber();
    let expectedLabelNumber: bigint;
    if (oldLabelNumber != null) {
      const one: bigint = BigInt(1);
      const oldNum: bigint = oldLabelNumber.currentValue;
      const localLabelNum: bigint = oldNum + one;
      expectedLabelNumber = localLabelNum;
    } else {
      expectedLabelNumber = ... redacted ...;
    }
```

I suspect its something to do with the flow typing of `oldLabelNumber`?? Although I would expect to see a `TypeError` on line 120 if this were the case.

`oldLabelNumber` is of type:

`{ currentValue: bigint } | null`

I only get this issue on our build sever. Locally it compiles & runs fine (same Node version and using the tsc from the local `node_modules/.bin`)

Probably worth noting that this is test code run via Jest.

CI Server Details:

- Node Version: 12.18.0
- Typescript: 4.1.3
- "@types/node": "^14.14.20"
- TS Config:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2019",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

- Jest config:

```json
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  testRegex: 'smoke\\.spec\\.ts$',
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/', '/dist/'],
  testTimeout: 30000,
};
```

Comment: `const oldNum: bigint` doesn't *make* `oldLabelNumber.currentValue` bigint, it just tells the compiler it is. You still need to convert it `const oldNum: bigint = BigInt(oldLabelNumber.currentValue);`

Comment: Are you sure it is a compilation error? It looks like a runtime error, maybe your build server runs some automated tests?

Comment: Ahhh so this is a runtime issue?!?! That makes a lot of sense

Comment: Thanks all. @VLAZ, do you want to post your comment as an answer?